# ReadAsMultipartAsync in Asp.net Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, resumablejs

i want use resumable.js in asp.net core but some codes not work in .net core , Example :

```
private async Task<bool> readPart(MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider)
{
    try
    {

        await  Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        ResumableConfiguration configuration = GetUploadConfiguration(provider);
                int chunkNumber = GetChunkNumber(provider);

        // Rename generated file
        MultipartFileData chunk = provider.FileData[0]; // Only one file in multipart message
                RenameChunk(chunk, chunkNumber, configuration.Identifier);

        // Assemble chunks into single file if they're all here
        TryAssembleFile(configuration);
                return true;
    }
    catch 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

how to change Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync for use in .net core ?

[ResumableController.cs](https://github.com/23/resumable.js/blob/master/samples/DotNET/Controllers/ResumableController.cs)

Comment: What you want is to upload file in asp.net core, right? If so, in asp.net core, `IFormfile` is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

According to the devs this extension has been updated for .net core. See this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/18848) on github.

Just download this nuget package and the extension will be available:

[Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.client)

Comment: no its not work , just  help to me , What is the equivalent of this code in .net core?

`await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);`